# Accessing Postgresql results

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I wrote a query and it returns a result set as below,

```
result = [
{"total_requests" : "4", "requesttimestamp" : null}, 
{"total_requests" : "2", "requesttimestamp" : null}, 
{"total_requests" : "4", "requesttimestamp" : null}, 
{"total_requests" : "7", "requesttimestamp" : null}, 
{"total_requests" : "1", "requesttimestamp" : 1.37412742E9}, 
{"total_requests" : "1", "requesttimestamp" : 1.37412781E9}, 
{"total_requests" : "1", "requesttimestamp" : 1.374127424E9}
]
```

When try to iterate through this as

```
result[i]["total_requests"] ,result[i]["requesttimestamp"]
```

to get the result pairs it gives as undefined.

So how to retrieve the value pairs seperately?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SQL. What are you using to access your postgres?

Comment: I am using Jaggery application and the results i got from query is attached above

Comment: For this question to make sense, you would have to provide the actual *data type* you return.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accessed through result[i].total_requests , result[i].requesttimestamp